# How to suppress Tooltip in built-in templates?

Tags: front-end, output-formatting, gui-construction, customization, tooltip

...or maybe switch the message. But I will be happy with no `Tooltip` at all.

[image]

I've naively tried with

```
Block[{$PerformanceGoal="Speed"}, ...]
```

because it works in case of `` Charts` `` tooltips, but with no effect :)

Comment: I looked through definitions. It seems that `Manipulator` uses `AnimatorBox` or `Animator` (you can check it by evaluating ``FE`Evaluate@
 FEPrivate`FrontEndResource["FEExpressions", "Manipulator04"][d2, d1, 
  mrange, a, b, e, c, ap, ii, o, i, ape, auto, av, Dynamic[open], 
  Dynamic[paused], Dynamic[rate], Dynamic[dir]]``). Maybe it is simpler to solve this problem with `Animator`, but I don't know how to go deeper :)

Comment: @ybeltukov That's only an example, dealing with it won't help with `Binomial` etc. I'm looking for sort of generic approach. Not sure it isn't out of scope, but folks here know surprising things :). Thanks for your attention.

Comment: I tried `SetOptions[.., 
 TooltipBoxOptions -> {TooltipDelay -> Infinity}]` on `$FrontEndSession`, `EvaluationNotebook[]` and as a cell option to no avail.  Also tried numeric delays.  Off on the wrong trail, I suppose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Quick fixes for specific cases

`TemplateBox` has `Tooltip` option so we can use it. There are three ways I'm aware of:

- go to `Core.nb` stylesheet, find `"Binomial"` style and add `Tooltip->None` to its `TemplateBoxOptions`.
- or you can target specific expression, the problem is that you have to be precise because `TemplateBoxOptions` will be overwritten by those from a stylesheet for a specific template [How to work with BoxOptions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/125765/5478)

  Here is the way to go in some cases:

  ```
  ToBoxes[
   TraditionalForm @ Binomial["a", "b"]
  ] /.  t : TemplateBox[_, "Binomial", ___] :> Append[t, Tooltip -> None] // RawBoxes
  ```
- or polish the definition

  ```
  Unprotect @ Binomial;

  Binomial /: MakeBoxes[ Binomial[a_, b_], fmt : TraditionalForm] := TemplateBox[
     {MakeBoxes[a, fmt], MakeBoxes[b, fmt]}, "Binomial", Tooltip -> None];

  Protect @ Binomial;

  TraditionalForm @ Binomial["as", "b"]
  ```

---

#### Rough approach:

Tooltip resources are stored in

```
FileNameJoin[{
 $InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "TextResources", "ToolTip.tr"}]
```

In order to not mess with installation directory you can copy this file to `$UserBaseDirectory/SystemFiles...` and replace labels you want. For example:

> @@resource ToolTipCut
>
> Cut   (*replace this line with your own label and save it.*)
>
> @|

- This is a global replacement so this and each next session will be affected.

Not a big deal if your goal is to customize tooltips in *Mathematica* for user/client who want's different language.

---

#### More flexible approach but very hairy:

- Case:

  Let's say we want to have one and only one `Manipulator` with changed labels.
- Idea:

  We are changing the file during initialization and replacing it back after cell contents are displayed. We have to force FrontEnd to forget cached string resources in between those steps.

  We will use here **undocumented** function:

  ```
  FrontEndExecute @ FrontEnd`FlushTextResourceCaches[]
  ```

  to force FrontEnd to forget current resurces.

---

```
(*aux. functions,
  you need to put them in to the initialization or something similar 
  if you want them to work after reopening the notebook*)

replaceTooltip[rules_List] :=  StringReplace[ file,
    ("\n" ~~ # ~~ "\n" :> "\n" <> #2 <> "\n") & @@@ rules]

exportAndFlush[msg_] := (
  Export[  
     FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd",
         "TextResources", "ToolTip.tr"}],
   replaceTooltip[msg],
   "Text"
   ];
  FrontEndExecute @ FrontEnd`FlushTextResourceCaches[]
  )
```

---

```
Dynamic[
  Manipulator[Dynamic@x, Appearance -> "Open"],
  None,
  Initialization :> (
    exportAndFlush[{"Play" -> "CustomPlayLabel"}];
    SetOptions[ EvaluationCell[],  CellDynamicExpression :> 
        Refresh[exportAndFlush[{"CustomPlayLabel" -> "Play"}], None]
    ];
  )
]
```

[image]

But when we create new one it will have default label:

```
Manipulator[Dynamic@x, Appearance -> "Open"]
```

[image]

#### Keep in mind:

- `FlushTextResourceCaches[]` is undocumented so maybe not stable, and not so fast. I haven't tested if one can flush resources partially, not globally.
- This approach is basing on the assumption that `CellDynamicExpression` fires after `Initialization`. Which is not described anywhere but seems to be true from my tests.

  Why we are using this, not just evalaute flush after cell is created? Because we want this label to be preserved between sessions and if you close the notebook and open again, resources are loaded again which would overwrite our label.
- Templates' tooltips, like `Binomial`, are stored in form of Rules

  > @@resource TemplateBoxTooltips { Abs" -> "Abs", ...

  so you have to extend  `replaceTooltip` function if you want to work with them.
- code above is only to show minimal example and describe the idea. for real app you need to add additional checks about the file about pattern you use for replacement etc. etc.

Comment: From your spelunking do you understand why `TooltipBoxOptions` fails?  Are the values hard-coded?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard No, sorry :/

Answer (score 4):

In version 7 this suppresses the **Show Animation Controls** tooltip but fails to suppress the **Play**, **Step Forward** etc. ones.

```
Style[
 Manipulate[Plot[Sin[x (1 + a x)], {x, 0, 6}], {a, 0, 2}],
 TooltipBoxOptions -> {DefaultLabelStyle -> {Opacity[0], 0}}
]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, in V9.0.1.0 it does not supress :/.

Comment: @Kuba Doesn't suppress anything?  Too bad.  I was hoping we could find a way to inject this setting into the template or template creation somehow.

Comment: No, Show animation controls is still there :/