# Show contour area as tooltip?

Tags: plotting, tooltip

I have contour plots, such as

```
plot = ContourPlot[Sqrt[(x - 2)^2 + (y - 2)^2 - 5], {x, -15, 15}, {y, -15, 15}, Contours -> {4}] /. _Polygon -> Sequence[]
```

I have successfully found the numerical area enclosed using Stokes' theorem, essentially the "x dy" case shown [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green's_theorem#Area_Calculation).

```
points = Transpose[Cases[Normal@plot, Line[pts_] :> pts, Infinity][[1, 
   All]]];  
area = N[Abs[Rest[First[points]].Last[ListCorrelate[{1, -1}, #1] & /@ points]]]
```

What I would like to accomplish now is to apply the found area as a `Tooltip[]` on the contour plot.

However, this isn't working properly:

```
Tooltip[ContourPlot[Sqrt[(x - 2)^2 + (y - 2)^2 - 5], {x, -15, 15}, {y, -15, 15}, Contours -> {4}] /. _Polygon -> Sequence[],"example"]
```

[image]

`"example"` comes up as a tooltip anywhere on the whole plot area, not just when the cursor is on the contour line. Also, sometimes it doesn't show "example"; it only shows like "ex" and then is cut off by white space.

How can I implement this properly?

Comment: [somehow related: how to suppress Tooltip](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40536/5478)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can proceed with `ReplaceAll`:

```
ContourPlot[Sqrt[(x - 2)^2 + (y - 2)^2 - 5], {x, -15, 15}, {y, -15, 15}, 
   Contours -> {4}
 ] /. _Polygon -> Sequence[] /. Tooltip[x_, y_] :> Tooltip[x, "example"]
```

[image]

In case of many contours you can take control this way:

```
ContourPlot[Sqrt[(x - 2)^2 + (y - 2)^2 - 5], {x, -15, 15}, {y, -15, 15}, 
            Contours -> {2, 4}
           ] /. _Polygon -> Sequence[] /. Tooltip[x_, 4] :> Tooltip[x, "example"]
```

so now only the chosen one is switched.

Comment: Thanks! This solution works I'm nearly certain, but I'm still having a display issue which I fear might be something else. Does anyone know why [this tooltip](http://i.imgur.com/WwFMbrO.png) is not showing fully?

Comment: @Steve I sometimes face this but I don't know the reason. Try maybe `Pane["exaple"]`.

Comment: Strange. Pane didn't fix it for me, but it did add a little extra white space below. Also, I tried "exampleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee" and the white box to the right extends. But the yellow background and text don't change, still "ex" and then cut off.

Comment: @Steve I think it is frequently faced issue. If you fail to find an answer with serach engine I encourage you to post the question.