# Tooltip not showing fully - mostly whitespace

Tags: tooltip

Here is an example of what I mean, the tooltip doesn't show most of the requested text ("example" in this case).

[image]

There is more information about my code in my previous [question: show contour area as tooltip](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40587/show-contour-area-as-tooltip?noredirect=1#comment121462_40587).

However, I made this post to address the display issue with the tooltip which is likely a broad problem.

Here is the code from the symptomatic screenshot I showed.

```
w = 4;
plot = ContourPlot[
    Sqrt[(x - 2)^2 + (y - 2)^2 - 5], {x, -15, 15}, {y, -15, 15}, 
    PlotPoints -> 30, MaxRecursion -> 4, Contours -> {w}, 
    ContourStyle -> Blue, ImageSize -> 250] /. _Polygon -> 
    Sequence[] /. Tooltip[x_, y_] :> Tooltip[x, "example"]
```

Which can be simplified to just

```
ContourPlot[
   Sqrt[(x - 2)^2 + (y - 2)^2 - 5], {x, -15, 15}, {y, -15, 15}, 
   Contours -> {4}] /. _Polygon -> Sequence[] /. 
 Tooltip[x_, y_] :> Tooltip[x, "example"]
```

and still have the same issue with the tooltip not showing.

I have tried adding a `Pane` wrapper around `"example"` within the argument of the last `Tooltip`, but this hasn't helped.

Comment: This example works well on Win7 V9.0.1.0 but I've faced this issue. And it was not stable, sometimes it occures, sometimes not.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior with the code in the question both in *Mathematica* 8.0.4 and 9.0.1 under Windows XP SP3. But I faced similar problems when used non-standard fonts for `Text` inside `Graphics`.

Comment: In order to reproduce this issue could you provide your PC's specs: Mma version, OS version, service pack level, video card and etc. I cannot reproduce the cut off tooltip with this example either.

Answer (score 6):

It's a bug. Wolfram is aware of it but has not chosen to fix it.

Sometimes I restart Mathematica to deal with it. If I am running something, for example, in a Manipulate function, I clear the local variables every time it is run. This helps most of the time.

Jeff