# Tooltips and points don't show when only 2 points in ListPlot?

Tags: plotting

Problem with `ListPlot` when each point has a `Tooltip` and there are exactly two points(or for a multi-plot `Listplot[{list1, list2...}]` with individual `Tooltip`s per point and each plot having exactly two points).

The points don't appear on the plot (or the associated tooltips) in the **3rd and 4th** case below.

1 point is ok, also 3 points or more is ok. I thought it might be to do with two points maybe being just outside the plot region, but extending `PlotRangePadding` and `PlotRange` didn't reveal the points.

Any ideas for a workaround? I've submitted this to support in case it is a bug.

```
ListPlot[{{{1, 1}, {2, 2}}, {{1, 1}, {2, 2}}}]
ListPlot[{{Tooltip[{1, 1}, "1"], Tooltip[{2, 2}, "2"]}, {Tooltip[{1, 1}, "1b"]}}]
ListPlot[{{Tooltip[{1, 1}, "1"], Tooltip[{2, 2}, "2"]},
          {Tooltip[{1.1, 1}, "1b"], Tooltip[{2.1, 2}, "2b"]}}]
ListPlot[{{Tooltip[{1, 1}, "1"], Tooltip[{2, 2}, "2"]}}]
ListPlot[{{Tooltip[{1, 1}, "1"], Tooltip[{2, 2}, "2"], Tooltip[{3, 3}, "3"]}}]
ListPlot[{{Tooltip[{1, 1}, "1"]}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I can confirm this behavior on 9.0.1 Windows - if you look at the `FullForm` of the affected plots, the list of points is empty.

Comment: Same on _v8_ Linux.

Comment: A permanent frustration. I recently put a bounty on this - to no avail. [link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40594/tooltip-not-showing-fully-mostly-whitespace)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appending an dummy "missing" point appears to work around this issue, e.g.:

```
test3 = {{Tooltip[{1, 1}, "1"], Tooltip[{2, 2}, "2"]}, 
         {Tooltip[{1, 1}, "1b"], Tooltip[{2, 2}, "2b"], Missing[]}};
test4 = {{Tooltip[{1, 1}, "1"], Tooltip[{2, 2}, "2"], Missing[]}};
```

Comment: @rasger, Excellent solution! That prompted me to do:If[Length[data[[i]]==2,Append[data[[i]],data[[i]][[-1]]]] so for lists of lists where some have 2 points, it duplicates the last point (otherwise ListLogPlot wasn't happy with Missing[])  Thank you.