# Can one effectively edit a Front End Resource that is already loaded?

Tags: front-end, customization, system-variables

A number of special definitions are loaded from `.tr` files on Front End initialization and are accessible via `FrontEndResource`.  These are used among other things for various menus and toolsbars, e.g.:

```
FrontEndResource["FEBitmaps", "HomeIconHot"] // ToExpression

FrontEndResource["FEExpressions", "HelpViewerToolbar"] // CellPrint

FrontEndResource["ContextMenus", "GraphicsBox"]

FrontEndResource["ColorSchemeSelector"] // CellPrint
```

The `.tr` resource files can be edited to change these as I proposed for [Can you make the new "Choose color scheme" helper larger?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54648/121) and [Is it possible to insert new colour schemes into ColorData?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/57885/121)  It would be much nicer to be able to edit these after they are loaded from within *Mathematica*.  One can [`Unprotect`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unprotect.html) `FrontEndResource` and modify the definition but this does not actually change what is displayed in the Front End.

As a simple example I would like to make the Color Scheme Selector a little wider so that it does not have a pointless horizontal scroll bar on my system.  I attempt:

```
Unprotect[FrontEndResource];

With[{FER := FrontEndResource["ColorSchemeSelector"]},
  FER = FER /. {180, Automatic} -> {195, Automatic};
]
```

The manually called resource is now wider:

```
FrontEndResource["ColorSchemeSelector"] // CellPrint
```

[image]

However the auto-complete popup for Color is not:

[image]

On examination this is not too surprising since the actual definition of `FrontEndResource` is:

```
FrontEndResource[name_] := 
  MathLink`CallFrontEnd[FrontEnd`Value[FEPrivate`FrontEndResource[name]]];

FrontEndResource[name_, sub_] := 
  MathLink`CallFrontEnd[FrontEnd`Value[FEPrivate`FrontEndResource[name, sub]]];
```

It seems logical that the Front End would make this lower level call directly, bypassing `` System`FrontEndResource ``.  My problem is that I don't know how to redefine this `` FrontEnd`Value ``. [`Names`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Names.html) finds a `` FrontEnd`SetValue `` which sounds promising but I haven't figured out how to use it.

How can I change this Front End Resource in a way that affects all appearances of the menu?

Comment: Closely related: [How to suppress Tooltip in built-in templates?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40536/5478), unfortunately I've failed to find equivalent of ``FrontEndExecute@FrontEnd`FlushTextResourceCaches[]`` for expressions' caches.

Comment: @Kuba Thanks for reminding me of that question, or more specifically your answer; I had forgotten. Even with that I see that you had to write to a `.tr` file rather than directly editing things in memory.  Perhaps these definitions are simply read only but I am hoping for authoritative confirmation of that before coming to a conclusion.

Comment: off-topic question, is there somewhere a generic topic about `With[{FER := `?

Comment: @Kuba I added this to [(121173)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/121173/121) for easy future reference.  Leonid writes in [(744)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/744/121) that he learned this syntax from Szabolcs so I probably did too, and just did not remember right.  Quite possibly it was discussed on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Kuba A likely origin of this (see comments): [(8742627)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8742627/).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard would something akin to what I did [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/145770/38205) work? By making the changes in a temporary directory it is like an in-place edit (although very crucially not).

Comment: @MB1965 That could be useful. Thanks.  For *my own needs* manually editing a copy of the files has been acceptable.  It seems you were also unable to figure out ``FrontEnd`SetValue``, if it actually does anything.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I've only ever seen it used as ``FrontEnd`SetValue[FEPrivate`Set[CurrentValue[spec],val]]``. That works fine, but doesn't really help us here. Once I figure out how to make the packets work I'll post a solution editing at the `DownValues` level on ``FrontEnd`Value``, but I have no experience with these WTSP packets so it's all very confusing.

Comment: @MB1965 I only skimmed your code and I have not yet tried it, but I don't see you getting around the need to restart *Mathematica*.  I mean for my example above the "manually called resource" would be changed but the "auto-complete popup" would not be changed until *Mathematica* is restarted; is that correct?  Or are you successfully performing a from-file refresh mid-session?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I get around that by prepending my temporary path to `{PrivatePaths, "TextResources"}` then by calling ``FrontEnd`FlushTextResourceCaches[]``. It reloads everything as one would hope--as long as one uses a resource name already known to the system.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard one caveat is that I haven't been able to get successful reloading with `KeyEventTranslations.tr` although I'm gonna keep playing with it. Reloading the menus works fine if you call `ResetMenusPacket[{Automatic,Automatic}]` (found in the PacletManager code) so I'm working on editing the `MenuSetup.tr` right now.

Comment: @MB1965 Nice. That will be useful indeed. +1 now. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I put up an example of what I'm doing with a link to the package [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/145847/how-can-i-customize-my-menus-without-reloading-menusetup-tr/145848#145848).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard this is way after the fact, of course, but I found [a comment by John Fultz](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6224/best-way-to-add-keyevents-and-faster-quit/6227#comment17859_6227) that suggests that even editing the .tr won't get the KeyEventTranslation in.

Comment: @b3m2a1 I think by *programmatically* he meant from within *Mathematica* itself, as editing the resource file has been effective in multiple versions.  Of course, it's not a supported function so it could change with any release; perhaps it already has as I still use v10.1

Comment: @Mr.Wizard sorry that's what I was getting at. I was hoping for a way to reload the resources without quitting or restarting Mathematica.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Oh, I understand now.  Thank you for pointing that out.  That likely applies here, but *maybe* other resources can be edited.  And if not now, perhaps in another version.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard other things can definitely be edited and reloaded within a session using that ``FrontEnd`FlushTextResourceCaches[]`` but I never figured out how to access those caches themselves. Maybe through ``Internal`CheckCache`` or something.

Answer (score 4):

This is more comment than answer as you want in-memory modification, but it is possible to force the text resources to be *reloaded*. You do this with, e.g.,

```
FrontEndExecute@
 FrontEnd`FlushTextResourceCaches[]
```

So you can make a new text resource in `$UserBaseDirectory` and have that reload. For example, let's make a new TR for the file headers:

```
$headersTR =
  FrontEndExecute@
   FrontEnd`FindFileOnPath[
    "FileHeaders.tr",
    "PrivatePathsTextResources"
    ];
$newHeadersTR =
  StringReplace[$headersTR,
   $InstallationDirectory -> $UserBaseDirectory
   ];
CreateDirectory[DirectoryName@$newHeadersTR,
  CreateIntermediateDirectories -> True];
Export[
  $newHeadersTR,
  "
  @@resource PackageHeader
  (*?__?*)

  @|
  ",
  "Text"
  ];
```

Then reload the headers:

```
FrontEndExecute@FrontEnd`FlushTextResourceCaches[]
FrontEndResourceString["PackageHeader"]

"(*?__?*)
"
```

And that'll change the package header in all your auto-generated .m files.

Note that this isn't in-memory modification, but I'm not wholly these are always stored in memory, as sometimes deleting a file causes the FE to spit an error when you try to load a resource from that file.

On the other hand, something definitely is stored in memory. E.g., try deleting that new package header TR and loading the header again:

```
DeleteFile[$newHeadersTR]
FrontEndResourceString["PackageHeader"]

"(*?__?*)
"
```

So that's there until the cache is flushed.

#### Update:

Here's a way to get it to spit an error:

```
Export[
  $newHeadersTR,
  "
  @@resource PackageHeader
  (*?__?*)

  @|
  ",
  "Text"
  ];
FrontEndExecute@FrontEnd`FlushTextResourceCaches[]
DeleteFile[$newHeadersTR];
FrontEndResourceString["PackageHeader"]

$Failed
```

Clearly the `FlushTextResourceCaches` found that `"PackageHeader"` was in `$newHeadersTR`, but didn't load it. My guess would be that it got added to `"ResourceMap.pbf"` (see below) or something, but the load doesn't get performed until later.

#### Cache files:

Just as one last note on these caches, there're these files:

```
FileNames["ResourceMap.pbf",
 FileNameJoin@{$UserBaseDirectory, "FrontEnd"},
 Infinity
 ]
```

which are what actually get overridden when you call:

```
FrontEndExecute@
 FrontEnd`FlushTextResourceCaches[]
```

And they're some scrambled binary format, but if you look at them in plain-text view you see the file names where the resources are stored, e.g. I found:

```
"/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/AddOns/Applications/NotebookTemplating/FrontEnd/TextResources/NotebookTemplatingResources.tr"
```

in it.

So presumably this file gets used as the `"ResourceMap"` to the front-end to tell it from where to load resources it doesn't have in memory. That may also explain why deleting a cached resource file sometimes throws errors.

Comment: Possibly the only answer possible at this time. Thanks for taking the time to write it up in detail.