# Hidden Notebooks?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, system

In *Mathematica*, almost everything is notebook: your "Untitled-1.nb" is a notebook, Help documentation are a series of notebooks, even those windows helping you to draw things or format your notebooks are, themselves, notebooks.

But I occasionally find some exceptions and I want to know what are they.

Run the following code and then open new palettes or notebooks, new names will bump out, but when opening the **"Preference"** window or **"Enter Activation Key"** window, nothing will happen.

```
Dynamic[Notebooks[], UpdateInterval -> 1]
```

Are they specially formatted and styled notebooks or some wierd things other than notebooks which are constructed using more basic form of programming? How can we know what's the content of them using something like `NotebookGet`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "Preferences" and "Enter Activation Key" windows are Palette Notebooks located in the directory

```
FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "SystemResources"}]
```

(look at "Preferences.nb" and "ActivationDialog.nb").

But (according to an old MathGroup post by John Fultz) the "Option Inspector" is written in C.

As to why `Notebooks[]` doesn't list them, I can only guess that the most probable reason is that they aren't *opened* by the FrontEnd in the usual way. Probably they are loaded as [Front End Resources](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/121059/280) or something similar. In support of this guess I can note that they don't appear in the list of recently opened files in the **File** menu when you open them as menu items (i.e. via **Edit ► Preferences...** and **Help ► Enter Activation Key...** ), but they **do** appear in this list when you open them directly by double-clicking in the File Explorer. And in the latter case they **are** listed by `Notebooks[]`!

Comment: But it's wierd that other Palette notebooks can be find in `Notebooks[]` but this two cannot, why will that happen?

Comment: @Wjx I updated the answer.

Comment: Well, but when opening other palettes, they will be shown in `Notebooks[]` but they won't appear in "recently opened" too.

Comment: @Wjx Notice that by "opening other palettes" you mean opening them via the **Palettes** menu, not via **File ► Open...**, right? If you use the latter method, they will do appear in the list of recently opened files. So we see that there are already two different *documented* ways to open a Palette. Since `FrontEndResource` by the essence is a Palette too, we have also third, undocumented way...

Answer (score 9):

With addition to Alexey's answer, *FrontEnd* probably hides them with:

```
 FrontEndExecute @ FrontEnd`SetNotebookInList[EvaluationNotebook[], False]
```

You can use it too to toggle appearance on `Notebooks[]` list.

Answer (score 6):

One other note, you can find every single notebook with:

```
FrontEndExecute@
 FrontEnd`ObjectChildren[$FrontEnd]
```