# Default styles for Exporting to PDF, EPS and SVG

Tags: front-end, export, stylesheet, pdf-format, inheritance

By default for on-screen display, `Rasterize` and `Export`ing to raster formats FrontEnd uses styles defined on the Notebook level via `StyleDefinitions` option:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 StyleDefinitions -> 
  Notebook[{
    Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]], 
    Cell[StyleData["My"], FontColor -> Red, FontWeight -> Bold, FontSize -> 20, FontFamily -> "Times"]
   }, 
   StyleDefinitions -> "PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"]]

text = Style["Text", 20, "My"]
Rasterize[text]
ImportString[ExportString[text, "TIFF"], "TIFF"]
```

> [image: output]
>
> [image: output]
>
> [image: output]

But local styles do not affect `Export`ing to vector graphics formats:

```
Export["temp.pdf", text] // SystemOpen
Export["temp.svg", text] // SystemOpen
```

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

**What determines the styles used *by default* for `Export`ing to PDF, EPS and SVG? Is it possible to change the defaults?**

Comment: @Kuba The question is, from where come the default styles and how to change them?

Comment: Ah, right, I missed the point. p.s. maybe related: [**87184**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/87184/5478)

Comment: Strongly related question with simpler workaround: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/160580/280

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DefaultStyleDefinitions.html),

> `DefaultStyleDefinitions` is a global option that specifies the default stylesheet for all new notebooks.

By spelunking `Export` with `` GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitionsLocal ``

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]
PrintDefinitionsLocal[Export]
```

one can find that for general `expr` `Export` first converts it into a Notebook using `` System`Convert`PDFDump`createVectorExportPacketExpr ``:

```
System`Convert`PDFDump`createVectorExportPacketExpr[expr]
```

> ```
> Notebook[{Cell[BoxData["expr"], "Output", ShowCellBracket -> False, 
>    CellMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}]}]
> ```

As one can see, this Notebook has no `StyleDefinitions` option what means that it has to inherit it from the global `DefaultStyleDefinitions`.

Hence default stylesheet used by `Export` is determined by `DefaultStyleDefinitions` option of `$FrontEndSession`.

---

#### Changing the default stylesheet

At first in the user profile directory I create custom stylesheet "DefaultMy.nb" based on "Default.nb" but with an additional style named "My":

```
dir = FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "StyleSheets"}];
If[! DirectoryQ[dir], CreateDirectory[dir]];
Export[FileNameJoin[{dir, "DefaultMy.nb"}], 
 Notebook[{Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]], 
   Cell[StyleData["My"], FontColor -> Red, FontWeight -> Bold, FontSize -> 250, 
    FontVariations -> {"Underline" -> True}, FontFamily -> "Algerian"]}, 
  StyleDefinitions -> "PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"]]
```

Now I set it as the value for `DefaultStyleDefinitions`:

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, DefaultStyleDefinitions] = "DefaultMy.nb"
```

After evaluating this `"DefaultMy.nb"` will be immediately opened as a [hidden](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/123519/280) Notebook what can be verified with the [code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/139993/280) provided by [MB1965](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/38205/mb1965):

```
Cases[FrontEndExecute@FrontEnd`ObjectChildren@$FrontEnd, 
 obj_ /; StringMatchQ[WindowTitle /. AbsoluteOptions[obj, WindowTitle], 
    "Default" ~~ __] :> {obj, WindowTitle /. AbsoluteOptions[obj, WindowTitle]}]
```

> ```
> {{NotebookObject[FrontEndObject[LinkObject["ca2gp_shm", 3, 1]], 12], "DefaultMy.nb"}, 
>  {NotebookObject[FrontEndObject[LinkObject["ca2gp_shm", 3, 1]], 4], "Default.nb"}}
> ```

If during current front end session there weren't invocations of `Export` to vector formats, this change will have immediate effect on `Export`. In the opposite case one should force FrontEnd to do something that will cause the [style definition cascade](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14835/280) to update: for example, an invocation of `Export`

```
ExportString["", "MGF"];
```

or `"ToggleShowExpression"` front end token (even when no `Cell` is selected)

```
FrontEndTokenExecute["ToggleShowExpression"]
```

does this. Other methods are discussed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/144991/280).

Now

```
text = Style["Algerian", 50, "My"];
ImportString[ExportString[text, "PDF"], "PDF"][[1]]
```

> [image: output]

Answer (score 3):

So I think this resolves at the `CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, DefaultStyleDefinitions]` level as can be seen by first finding the notebook object that tracks these styles and inserting your definition there:

```
defaultStylingNotebook =
  First@
   Select[
    FrontEndExecute@FrontEnd`ObjectChildren@$FrontEnd,
    (WindowTitle /. AbsoluteOptions[#, WindowTitle]) == 
      CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, DefaultStyleDefinitions] &
    ];

NotebookWrite[defaultStylingNotebook,
 Cell[StyleData["My"], FontColor -> Red, FontWeight -> Bold, 
  FontSize -> 20, FontFamily -> "Times"]
 ]
```

Now running this:

```
text = Style["Text", "My"];

Export[
  FileNameJoin@{$TemporaryDirectory, "temp.pdf"},
  text
  ] // Import
```

I get the red import one would expect:

[image: test]

If you want a work around without doing anything so drastic as this, try this:

```
text=Style["Text",CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[],{StyleDefinitions,"My"}]]
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55323/discussion-on-answer-by-mb1965-default-styles-for-exporting-to-pdf-eps-and-svg).