# Forcing the front end to update style definitions

Tags: front-end, stylesheet, customization, display, inheritance

#### tl;dr

I need a way to apply style edits in stylesheets, even when I can't use cmd+Shift+E

#### ntl;wr

A while back I wrote a suite of stylesheet editing tools to automate operations I did in batch, which basically just finds all `Cell[StyleData[style],___]` cells. The tools work great, except for when I need to apply the edits I've performed.

For example, try this:

```
new = CreateDocument[Cell[BoxData@"input", "Input"],
   System`ClosingSaveDialog -> False];
SetOptions[new,
  StyleDefinitions ->
   Notebook[{
     Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]],
     Cell[StyleData["Input"]],
     Cell[BoxData@ToBoxes@Unevaluated@
         SetOptions[Cells[][[2]],
          Background -> LightBlue
          ],
      "Input",
      InitializationCell -> True],
     Cell[BoxData@ToBoxes@Unevaluated[
         SelectionMove[
          Cells[][[2]],
          All,
          Cell
          ];
         FrontEndTokenExecute@"ToggleShowExpression"; 
         FrontEndTokenExecute@"ToggleShowExpression";
         ],
      "Input"]
     },
    StyleDefinitions -> "PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"]
  ];
FrontEndTokenExecute[new, "EditStyleDefinitions"];
FrontEndTokenExecute["EvaluateInitialization"]
```

It'll apply the styling with `SetOptions` but doesn't update.

I can force updating using the `"ToggleShowExpression"` calls in the second input cell there, but that only works if I can actually move to the cell.

Usually I'm building styles in a notebook, so I can, but sometimes this doesn't work. Case in point, I've recently been playing with the hidden style notebooks that Mathematica opens to track style changes. E.g.

```
$DefaultStyleNotebook :=
 
 SelectFirst[FrontEndExecute@FrontEnd`ObjectChildren[$FrontEnd], 
  Quiet@NotebookFileName@# ===
    
    FileNameJoin@{$InstallationDirectory,
      "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "StyleSheets", "Default.nb"} &
  ]
```

That's the (usually hidden) notebook that sets all the default styles. Now I can set its properties using `StylesheetEdit[style, ops]`, but the changes can't be applied because I can't use `"ToggleShowExpression"`.

I've looked through many of the front-end packets, but can't find where whatever "cascade-update" type functionality the front end uses to apply these updates is hidden.

Can anyone help me out? Note that the real dream would be something that I can just evaluate in the kernel, but which preserves the `CellObject`. (i.e. no rewriting with `NotebookWrite`)

#### Example

As an example this is the sort of syntax I'm using:

```
SSEdit["Input", True,
 FontColor -> Red
 ]
```

where the `True` just means create a new `Cell` with `StyleData["Input",...]` if it doesn't exist in the style definitions notebook.

After application this is what we see:

[image: apply]

And then we revert it like this:

```
SSEdit["Input", True,
 FontColor -> Inherited
 ]
```

Which we can see does indeed revert the change:

[image: revert]

But here's the annoying code I have to use to get those changes to apply:

```
SSApplyEdits[cells : {__CellObject}] :=     
 With[{e = EvaluationCell[]},
  Do[
   SelectionMove[c, All, Cell,
    AutoScroll -> False];
   FrontEndTokenExecute[ParentNotebook@c,"ToggleShowExpression"];
   FrontEndTokenExecute[ParentNotebook@c,"ToggleShowExpression"];,
   {c, cells}
   ];
   SelectionMove[e, After, Cell]
   ];
```

Comment: According to my experiments, changes applied to the in-memory `"Default.nb"` via yours `$DefaultStyleNotebook` have immediate effect on the opened Notebooks (checked with *Mathematica* 11.1.1 on Windows 7 x64). Is the situation different for you? From the other hand, have you tried `FrontEndTokenExecute[$DefaultStyleNotebook, "ToggleShowExpression"]`?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov when I use `SetOptions` the changes don't immediately apply. Same goes when I use it on something other than the `$DefaultStyleNotebook`. The `"ToggleShowExpression"` only works when the cell is selected in the notebook. When I get a chance I'll try just using `ExportPacket` on the notebook. Ought to apply the changes, I think.

Comment: In my comment I meant editing the in-memory stylesheet programmatically like you showed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/139993/280). What practical applications has `SetOptions` on the in-memory stylesheet (I just can't imagine)?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I have code that finds the `StyleData` cells and then I use `SetOptions` on those. Originally I did this with the style notebook open and so `"ToggleShowExpression"` sufficed but once I moved to the hidden in-memory notebooks my original code failed. Supplying the notebook object to `"ToggleShowExpression"` works, but opening and closing the cells can be incredibly distracting, so hopefully `ExportPacket` will do.

Comment: Note that instead of `SetOptions` you always can use `NotebookRead` - `Insert` - `NotebookWrite` on a `CellObject`. But it will open closed cell groups unfortunately. An alternative is an in-memory modification of the stylesheet Notebook expression as a whole and then writing it instead of the original using `NotebookPut`.

Comment: Also `"ToggleShowExpression"` works even when no cell is selected, so you can simply deselect the cell before calling it.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I want to preserve the `CellObject` so no rewrite will do it for me. `ExportPacket` works but makes an annoying beep I'll have to deal with. `"ToggleShowExpression"` with no selection doesn't trigger updates. Let me post an example of the kind of thing I'm doing. Might clarify things some.

Comment: I've found that simple ``FrontEndExecute@ExportPacket[]`` doesn't work for updating the styles after `SetOptions` (as well as `Rasterize[""]`) but ``FrontEndExecute@ExportPacket[Notebook[{Cell[""]}], "BoundingBox"]`` works, and ``ExportString["", "MGF"]`` also works.

Comment: `NotebookWrite[cellObject, Cell[StyleData["Input"], ...]]` doesn't destroy the `CellObject`.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov it does for me at least. Try this: 
`c = EvaluationCell[];NotebookWrite[c, NotebookRead@c];c === EvaluationCell[]`. Even if you evaluate this in two steps: `c = EvaluationCell[];NotebookWrite[c, NotebookRead@c];` and `PreviousCell[] === c` you still get `False`.

Comment: Yes, indeed. `NotebookWrite` simply didn't work for the stylesheet because it has `Editable -> False`.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov for whatever reason this solution isn't updating *all* style definitions for me anymore. Does it still work for you?

Comment: Which solution do you mean specifically? And which style definitions it doesn't update / update now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Updating the style definition cascade after in-memory modification of a stylesheet using `SetOptions`

I've found that simple (and invalid) `FrontEndExecute@ExportPacket[]` doesn't work for this purpose but a valid `ExportPacket` works:

```
FrontEndExecute@ExportPacket[Notebook[{Cell[""]}], "BoundingBox"]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.0135368, Null}
> ```

(instead of `"BoundingBox"` one can request [`"InputText"` or `"PlainText"`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1411/280) what appears to be slightly faster).

How I tested this. First, I find the cell defining the `"Input"` style:

```
input = Select[Cells[$DefaultStyleNotebook], 
    First@NotebookRead[#] === StyleData["Input"] &][[1]];
```

Then I apply `SetOptions` on it:

```
SetOptions[input, {FontSize -> 16}]
```

Nothing is changed visually. Now after evaluating

```
FrontEndExecute@ExportPacket[Notebook[{Cell[""]}], "BoundingBox"];
```

The font size of the input cells changes...

---

**Update: additional methods**

It is sufficient just to create an invisible `Notebook` and immediately close it for forcing the style definitions cascade to update:

```
NotebookClose[CreateNotebook[Visible -> False]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.0696042, Null}
> ```

Toggling dynamic updating *twice* also works (and for a stylesheet it should be safe since it shouldn't contain `Dynamic` elements)

```
Do[FrontEndExecute[
   FrontEndToken[$DefaultStyleNotebook, "ToggleDynamicUpdating"]], {2}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.0126106, Null}
> ```

Comment: Fascinating. I wonder why that is. Works for me though too.

Comment: @MB1965 I've updated the answer with additional methods.

Comment: I commented on the wrong thing... (thought I was commenting on this) I meant the first solution for the in-memory modification. I made changes it in a stylesheet notebook and the definitions didn't cascade out to the proper notebook.

Comment: Just tested and for whatever reason none of these are working now. It might be my 23 open notebooks (most of these are hidden FE notebooks, but maybe it tracks them?) but I'm not sure what's going on. The explicit double `"ToggleShowExpression"` still works, but, of course, that's an annoyingly clumsy solution.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Have you tried asking the tech support on this issue? Of course they can refuse supporting undocumented functionality, but you can re-formulate the question in such a way that only documented functionality will be concerned.

Answer (score 1):

So I discovered the problem is just fundamentally that I'm an idiot. The issue wasn't that the notebook wasn't visible. It's that `"ToggleShowExpression"` was being called on the wrong notebook.

For completeness here's how I'm doing it:

```
StylesheetApplyEdits[cells : {__CellObject}] :=

  With[{e = EvaluationCell[]},
   Do[
    SelectionMove[c, All, Cell,
     AutoScroll -> False];
    FrontEndTokenExecute[ParentNotebook@c, "ToggleShowExpression"]; 
    FrontEndTokenExecute[ParentNotebook@c, "ToggleShowExpression"];,
    {c, cells}];
   SelectionMove[e, After, Cell]
   ];
StylesheetApplyEdits[nb : _CellObject | Automatic : Automatic] :=

  StylesheetApplyEdits[{Replace[nb, Automatic :> EvaluationCell[]]}];
```

This now works, so I can do silly things like:

```
SSEdit[$DefaultStyleNotebook, "Notebook",
 Background -> LightBlue
 ]
```

And all my style definitions update without me having to edit `"Default.nb"`.

I'm still interested in the best way to do this, though. Surely there's a better way than using a front-end token.

Answer (score 1):

**Warning: this answer is about updating the *default* style definitions after changing `CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, DefaultStyleDefinitions]` as shown [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/140003/280). About updating the style cascade after in-memory modification of a stylesheet using `SetOptions` see another answer in this thread.**

---

One simple way to force updating of the style definitions is to invoke `Export` or `Rasterize` with a blank string:

```
ExportString["", "MGF"]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.0522419, Null}
> ```

```
Rasterize[""]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.0437933, Null}
> ```

More efficient approach is to call `FrontEndExecute@ExportPacket[]` directly:

```
FrontEndExecute@ExportPacket[] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.00790514, $Failed}
> ```

(it does update the style definitions despite `$Failed`).

It seems to be as efficient as `FrontEndTokenExecute["ToggleShowExpression"]` but has no drawback of potentially changing the state of selected cell(s):

```
FrontEndTokenExecute["ToggleShowExpression"] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.00952195, Null}
> ```

Comment: Fantastic. Does calling `ExportPacket[] ` update all notebook styles or just the selected notebook? That is, my issue previously had been that I needed styles in a hidden stylesheet to update, but the problem was doing this in an unselected notebook.

Comment: @MB1965 I performed my tests by changing `CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, DefaultStyleDefinitions]` as shown [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/140003/280). So actually I tested updating the *default* styles for newly created notebooks.

Comment: Okay I'll do some testing then. I don't really care about about updating default styles, just want to be able to apply edits I set in stylesheets programatically--even when the stylesheet notebook is one of the hidden ones that doesn't show up in `Notebooks[]`.