# How to programmatically change CellStyle of all Cells from "Input" to "Code"?

Tags: programming, notebooks, cells, style

I have a special notebook styled for only creating functions and their packages. I often lazily do `Evaluate Notebook` instead of finding and opening all cells I need for testing code. For this to work I need to make certain that only relevant cells are styled for `Input`. I edited my stylesheet so that cells with `CellStyle Code` are never evaluated (with different colors) this way no symbols clash and bad or redundant definitions are prevented.

Because I usually only need to evaluate 2 or 3 cells at time it is best to change all `Input CellStyle`-s to `Code` then I can manually find and only change those `Cells` I need to run to `CellStyle "Input"`.

So basically the function should search entire `EvaluationNotebook[]` for all cells with `CellStyle \[Rule] "Input"` and change each found with `CellStyle \[Rule] "Code"`.

So far all 4 of my desperate attempts `Failed` although they all correctly found all `Input Cells`. I suspect I'm *close but no dice*.

First install needed resources...

```
ResourceFunction["PersistResourceFunction"]["PersistResourceFunction"]
PersistResourceFunction["SelectByCurrentValue"]
```

My 4 attempts...

```
NotebookFind[EvaluationNotebook[], "Input", All, CellStyle] /. 
 "Input" -> "Code"
SelectByCurrentValue[Cells[], Evaluatable] /. "Input" -> "Code"
cells = Cells[CellStyle -> "Input"]
CurrentValue[cells, CellStyle] = "Code"
Replace[#, "Input" -> "Code"] & /@ cells
```

Comment: What about using `SetOptions` to change the options Evaluatable and Background instead?

Comment: @CarlWoll although that is practical i would like to be able to do this for almost any `CellStyle` or other properties. so it's more of a learning exercise for me.

Comment: You can press `Alt` key (might be other keys on OS other than Windows) and left click the bracket of a certain cell to select all cells with the same style in the same notebook.

Comment: @Silvia wonderful tip. wolfram does a great job off making certain all keyboard shortcuts work for all operating systems even if keys are named differently.

Comment: Is this what you are after? [Set the style of a cell](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/78774/5478)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Fixing problems with your preferred solution

> **Edit: Solution 3 Refactored DOES NOT WORK AS EXPECTED**
>
> It only works in limited cases where I find `Cells` by their `CellStyle` and change `CellStyle` but not if I mix-n-match different properties for finding and changing. I don't know why that is. If you have insight please contribute.

Stricly speaking, the usage of `All` as the trird argument of `Replace` (as well as usage of `ReplaceAll`) is dangerous because it means that the replacement will be performed on all levels of the original `Cell` expression (returned by `NotebookRead`), while you wish to modify only the `Rest` of the latter. Hence the **Solution 3** should be rewritten as follows in order to make it safe:

```
NotebookWrite[#, 
   Block[{cellExpr = NotebookRead[#]}, 
    Join[cellExpr[[1 ;; 1]], 
         Replace[Rest[cellExpr], "Input" -> "Code", {1}]]]] & /@ 
 Cells[CellStyle -> "Input"]
```

The reason why your `replaceCellOps` doesn't allow to "mix-n-match different properties for finding and changing" is that you designed it in the way which normally doesn't allow to do this. Here is a safe version which allows arbitrary replacements in the list of cell options:

```
Clear[replaceCellOptions]
replaceCellOptions[rules_, cells_] := 
  Block[{cellExpr = NotebookRead[#]}, 
     If[Head[cellExpr] === Cell, 
      NotebookWrite[#, 
       Join[cellExpr[[1 ;; 1]], 
        Replace[Rest[cellExpr], rules, {1}]]]]] & /@ cells;
```

Usage example (it will change styles of all `"Input"` cells to `"Code"` and prepend `"Code "` to their cell labels):

```
replaceCellOptions[{"Input" -> "Code", 
  HoldPattern[CellLabel -> label_] :> CellLabel -> "Code " <> label}, 
 Cells[CellStyle -> "Input"]]
```

---

### Better solution: Stylesheet-based approach

An alternative solution which is both much more efficient and safe is to manupulate the private Notebook's stylesheet in order to change the style of cells, as shown [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/259606/280).

Replace `"Input"` style with `"Code"` style:

```
SetOptions[
    EvaluationNotebook[],
    StyleDefinitions -> Notebook[
        {
        Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]],
        Cell[StyleData["Input", StyleDefinitions -> StyleData["Code"]]]
        }
    ]
]
```

Now input cells are formatted with `"Code"` style, while in their definitions they still have style `"Input"`:

[image: screenshot]

You can change arbitrary `Cell` options via private stylesheet. For example, make `"Input"` cells not just formatted with `"Code"` style, but also `Italic`:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 StyleDefinitions -> 
  Notebook[{Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]], 
    Cell[StyleData["Input", StyleDefinitions -> StyleData["Code"]], 
     FontSlant -> Italic]}]]
```

If you wish to replace one of the `"Code"` style definitions for `"Input"` cells, you should place the "intercept" before the line `Cell[StyleData["Input", StyleDefinitions -> StyleData["Code"]]`. For example, making the font weight to be `Plain` (instead of `Bold` by default):

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], StyleDefinitions -> Notebook[{
    Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]],
    Cell[StyleData["Input"], FontWeight -> Plain],
    Cell[StyleData["Input", StyleDefinitions -> StyleData["Code"]]],
    }]]
```

Reset everything to the defaults:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]
```

P.S. To force updating the styles of the notebook you may need to evaluate

```
FrontEndTokenExecute["ToggleShowExpression"]
```

or

```
NotebookClose[CreateNotebook[Visible -> False]]
```

as described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/141499/280).

Comment: thank you for responding to this so quickly. I didnt expect to see a response in months if ever. This is also the only time ive ever seen `HoldPattern` used outside of `General Tag Messages` for errors. I cant wait to  try it. Ill leave a comment sometime next week and give you input. :)

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
Scan[(CurrentValue[#, StyleNames] = "Code")&, Cells[CellStyle -> "Input"]]
```

or

```
SetOptions[#, "Code"]& /@ Cells[CellStyle -> "Input" ]
```

or

```
NotebookWrite[#, Replace[NotebookRead[#],"Input" -> "Code", All]]& /@ 
  Cells[CellStyle -> "Input"]
```

or, using `ReplaceAll`,

```
NotebookWrite[#, ReplaceAll["Input"->"Code"] @ NotebookRead @ #]& /@ 
   Cells[CellStyle -> "Input"]
```

[image]

**Update:** The last 2 can be turned into functions with two optional arguments as follows:

```
ClearAll[replaceCellOps1, replaceCellOps2]
replaceCellOps1[from_: "Input", to_ : "Code"] := 
 Map[NotebookWrite[#, Replace[NotebookRead @ #, from -> to, All]] &]@
  Cells[CellStyle -> from]

replaceCellOps2[from_: "Input", to_ : "Code"] := 
 Map[NotebookWrite[#, ReplaceAll[from -> to] @ NotebookRead @ #] &]@
  Cells[CellStyle -> from]
```

Comment: it sort of kind of works. please view my answer for a detailed explanation and a suggestion on how it might be fixed.

Comment: (1) although 3rd solution works i have a habit of refactoring to a function that takes arguments for different cases of properties and values. here it is. i hope you like: `replaceCellOps[from_ : "Input", to_ : "Code", 
   cells_ : Cells[CellStyle -> "Input"]] := 
  NotebookWrite[#, Replace[NotebookRead[#], from -> to, All]] & /@ 
   cells;` (2) i feel like i got real close with my 4 attempts using 3 with `ReplaceAll` and one with `Map`. how would you fix any of them. im dying to know. lol

Comment: @JulesManson, I like `replaceCellOps`; we need a small change to make it work in both directions (see my update). Re (2) I expected `(CurrentValue[#,  CellStyle] = "Code")&/@cells` to work; I don't know why it doesn't.

Answer (score 5):

**This is not a real answer but a detailed explanation of performance issues with member kglr's first two solutions. Use third solution. It works perfectly.**

**Solution 1: Scan**

```
Scan[(CurrentValue[#, StyleNames] = "Code")&, Cells[CellStyle -> "Input"]
```

It sort of kind of works. Yes it seems to set `CellStyle StyleNames` from `"Input"` to `"Code"` by appending `"Code"` after `"Input"`. So it doesn't actually remove (or replace) `"Input"`. This can be seen with `Cell -> Show Expression`.

Original `Input` test `Cell` before invoking `Scan[...]`

```
Symbol@ToString@z
Head@z
z=2+2
Head@z
```

`Show Expression` of test `Cell` after Invoking `Scan[...]`...

```
Cell[BoxData[{
 RowBox[{"Symbol", "@", 
  RowBox[{"ToString", "@", "z"}]}], "\[IndentingNewLine]", 
 RowBox[{"Head", "@", "z"}], "\[IndentingNewLine]", 
 RowBox[{"z", "=", 
  RowBox[{"2", "+", "2"}]}], "\[IndentingNewLine]", 
 RowBox[{"Head", "@", "z"}]}], "Input", "Code",
 CellLabel->"In[18]:="]
```

This results in an `Input Cell` with all the properties and formats of `Code Cells` which are distinguishable by their `StyleSheet` settings for `Background Color`, `Font Color`, `FontFace`, etc and most importantly that `Evaluatable -> False`. In addition checking right-context menu for `Style` still shows `Input` highlighted. This solution does work when I dont want these cells evaluated.

However changing `Code Cells` back to `Input` which will eventually need to be done for most of them can be a little bit cumbersome. It requires 3 manual steps: (1) in right-click context menu set `Style` from `Input` to `Code`. (2) repeat in reverse: `Code` to  `Input`. (3) from main menu do `Format -> Clear Formatting`.

Luckily kglr is a standup guy. He has since added two more solutions. I can't wait to try them. :)

**Solution 2: SetOptions**

Unfortunately this gives the very same results as Solution 1

```
SetOptions[#, "Code"]& /@ Cells[CellStyle -> "Input" ]
```

**Solution 3: NotebookWrite**

```
NotebookWrite[#, Replace[NotebookRead[#], "Input" -> "Code", All]] & /@
  Cells[CellStyle -> "Input"]
```

*Third's are always a charm.* This one works perfectly. Thank you so much kglr. I will add this as a `Button` for my `DockedCell` toolbar where I put my most essential functions. :)

**Solution 3 Refactored: to broaden scope**

I anchored it to a function so that it can accept almost any properties and values. That is how much I <3 this solution. :)

```
replaceCellOps[from_ : "Input", to_ : "Code", 
   cells_ : Cells[CellStyle -> "Input"]] := 
  NotebookWrite[#, Replace[NotebookRead[#], from -> to, All]] & /@ 
   cells;
```

**Edit: Solution 3 Refactored DOES NOT WORK AS EXPECTED**

It only works in limited cases where I find `Cells` by their `CellStyle` and change `CellStyle` but not if I mix-n-match different properties for finding and changing. I don't know why that is. If you have insight please contribute.