# How to create and use my own *.tr FrontEndResource and FrontEndResourceString files

Tags: programming, front-end, gui-construction, customization, user-interface

Various Mathematica user interfaces are Mathematica notebook files. It seems to be quite common for these notebook files to contain only part of the information in themselves and to load different elements from one or multiple *.tr files via `FrontEndResource` or `FrontEndResourceString`. Some of the user interfaces are entirely based on a *.tr file. One example for these is the `"ColorSchemeSelector"`, which can be displayed in the front-end using

```
FrontEndResource["ColorSchemeSelector"] // CellPrint
```

and is based on

```
FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "TextResources", 
 "ColorSchemeSelector.tr"}]
```

How to create and use such files for my own applications?

For illustration purpose, here is an example for an user interface (without any function) that makes use of different parts of multiple front-end resource files that are part of Mathematica.

```
Panel @ Grid[
  {
   {FrontEndResourceString["codeAssistColorSchemeChooseMenuString"], 
    SpanFromLeft},
   {ToExpression@FrontEndResource["FEExpressions", "TimeObjectIcon"], 
    ToExpression@FrontEndResource["SliderBarHorizontal"]},
   {},
   {Button[FrontEndResource["ColorSchemeChooserStrings", "okButtonText"], 
     Null],
    Button[FrontEndResourceString["yesButtonText"], Null]}
   }]
```

[image: Example]

I'd want the *.tr file to be located within the folder structure of the app. However, as it is part of this question how to get that working and to test what works as expected, I copied the relatively empty *TokenTranslationDictionary.tr* into my `$UserBaseDirectory`

```
CopyFile[FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "TextResources", 
    "TokenTranslationDictionary.tr"}], 
 FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "TextResources",
    "TokenTranslationDictionary.tr"}]]
```

and replaced the

```
{
}
```

with

```
{
"testText" -> "just some text",
"testText2" -> "some more text"
}
@|
@| just a comment
@|
@@resource myFEResource1
resource1
@|
@@resource myFEResource2
{
"TestText" -> "this is resource 2"
}
@|
```

which should be the correct syntax, base on the other *.tr files.

Nevertheless, after restarting Mathematica only

```
FrontEndResource["TokenTranslationDictionary", "testText"]
```

> `"just some text"`

and

```
FrontEndResource["TokenTranslationDictionary", "testText2"]
```

`"some more text"`

return the expected output. But

```
FrontEndResourceString["myFEResource1"]
```

and

```
FrontEndResource["myFEResource2", "TestText"]
```

return

> `$Failed`

Therefore it appears to me that the available `resource`s are defined somewhere and not even adding a new `resource` to an existing *.tr file is possible.

How to make it possible to use my own *.tr files with their own `resource` definitions via `FrontEndResource` and `FrontEndResourceString`?

If that is not possible, what are the best alternatives that allow a similar information organization and importing by the front-end?

Comment: John Fultz said there is no workflow for users but the whole resources setup is meant to be changed as it is old and doesn't fit modern Mathematica. Yet he didn't give any estimation of when one could expect this to be done.

Comment: I was thinking about using `$FrontEndSession's` `TaggingRules` as a replacement, what do you think?

Comment: @Kuba Sounds like an interesting approach. One could ,e.g., separate the design code from the logic code by putting the design stuff into a file that sets the `TaggingRules` and then use the front-end in the logic file to get the design elements. As long as one isn't using big graphics, pre-occupying the memory isn't a problem and could remove the delays one experiences when using `FrontEndResource`.

Comment: I will try to use it in a project in near future so I will share my experience later.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a sample way you could do something sorta like this.

Clearly there's some bound list of resources proper that I don't yet know how to edit (despite many `` FrontEnd`SetValue `` tests and much grepping). We can take advantage of the list-of-rules format of these resources though.

I'll stick with your idea of replacing TokenTranslationDictionary.

All we'll really be doing is copying and saving files in some pre-specified directory. I thought I'd use the `$TemporaryDirectory` but I'm leaving the structure as if it were `$UserBaseDirectory` so it's a simple change if you want permanent resources:

```
$FETrBaseName =
  "TokenTranslationDictionary";
$FETrFileBaseName =
  "ExtendedFEResources";
If[! ListQ@$FETrResources,
  $FETrResources =
   FrontEndResource[$FETrBaseName]
  ];
$FETrBaseFile =
  FileNameJoin@{
    $InstallationDirectory,
    "SystemFiles",
    "FrontEnd",
    "TextResources",
    "TokenTranslationDictionary.tr"
    };
$FEResourceCompleteListing =
  StringCases[
      Import[#, "Text"] & /@

       FileNames["*.tr", 
        FileNameJoin@{$InstallationDirectory, 
          "SystemFiles"}, \[Infinity]],
      "@@resource " ~~ w : WordCharacter .. :> w
      ] // Flatten // DeleteDuplicates // Sort;
$FETrListing =
  AssociationMap[
   Null &,
   $FEResourceCompleteListing
   ];
$FEResourceDirectory =
  FrontEnd`FileName@{
    $TemporaryDirectory,
    "SystemFiles",
    "FrontEnd",
    "TextResources"
    };
```

Then we'll write our load function to configure everything:

```
FELoadResources[] := (
   CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession,
     {PrivatePaths, "TextResources"}
     ] =
    DeleteDuplicates@
     Prepend[
      CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession,
       {PrivatePaths, "TextResources"}
       ],
      FrontEnd`FileName[
       Evaluate@{ToFileName @@ $FEResourceDirectory}
       ]
      ];
   FrontEndExecute@FrontEnd`FlushTextResourceCaches[]
   );
```

Then a bit of export work:

```
$FETrTemplate =
  "@|
  @|
  @@resource `name`
  `value`
  @|
  ";
FETrExport[name_, value_, inputForm : True | False : True] :=

  If[value === Inherited,
   Quiet@DeleteFile@
      ToFileName @@
    Append[$FEResourceDirectory,
     If[StringQ@name,
      name <> ".tr",
      Last@name <> ".tr"
      ]
     ],
   Quiet@
    CreateDirectory[
     ToFileName @@ $FEResourceDirectory,
     CreateIntermediateDirectories -> True
     ];
   Export[
    ToFileName @@
     Append[$FEResourceDirectory,
      If[StringQ@name,
       name <> ".tr",
       Last@name <> ".tr"
       ]
      ],
    TemplateApply[
     $FETrTemplate, <|
      "name" ->
       If[StringQ@name,
        name,
        First@name
        ],
      "value" ->
       If[inputForm,
        ToString[value, InputForm],
        value
        ]
      |>],
    "Text"
    ]
   ];
FEAddResource[name_String, value_] := (
   If[KeyMemberQ[$FETrListing, name],
    FETrExport[name, value, False],
    $FETrResources =
     Normal@DeleteCases[Inherited]@
       Merge[{$FETrResources, name -> value}, Last];
    Quiet@
     CopyFile[$FETrBaseFile,
      ToFileName @@
       Append[$FEResourceDirectory,
        FileNameTake@$FETrFileBaseName]
      ];
    FETrExport[
     $FETrBaseName -> $FETrFileBaseName,
     $FETrResources
     ]
    ];
   FELoadResources[]
   );
FEAddResource[r : {(_String -> _) ..}] := (
   $FETrResources =
    Normal@DeleteCases[Inherited]@
      Merge[{$FETrResources, r}, Last];
   Quiet@
    CopyFile[$FETrBaseFile,
     ToFileName @@
      Append[$FEResourceDirectory,
       $FETrFileBaseName <> ".tr"
       ]
     ];
   FETrExport[
    $FETrBaseName -> $FETrFileBaseName,
    $FETrResources
    ]
   );
```

And then add a layer on `FrontEndResource`:

```
$FEExtraResources = True;
Unprotect /@ {FrontEndResource, FrontEndResourceString};
FrontEndResource[
    k_String?(! KeyMemberQ[$FETrListing, #] &)
    ] /; TrueQ@$FEExtraResources :=

  FrontEndResource[$FETrBaseName, k];
FrontEndResource /:
  Set[
    FrontEndResource[k_String],
    v_
    ] /; TrueQ@$FEExtraResources :=
  (FEAddResource[k, v]; v);
FrontEndResourceString /:
  Set[
    FrontEndResourceString[k_String?(KeyMemberQ[$FETrListing, #] &)],
    v_
    ] /; TrueQ@$FEExtraResources :=
  (FEAddResource[k, ToString@v]; 
   FrontEndResourceString[k]);
Protect /@ {FrontEndResource, FrontEndResourceString};
```

And when we test it:

```
In[134]:= FrontEndResource // DownValues // Length
FrontEndResource["asd"] = 2;
FrontEndResource // DownValues // Length
FrontEndResource["asd"]


Out[134]= 3

Out[136]= 3

Out[137]= 2
```

This also works for proper resources:

```
In[144]:= FrontEndResource // DownValues // Length
FrontEndResource["PackageHeader"] = "Package[%s]";
FrontEndResource // DownValues // Length
FrontEndResourceString["PackageHeader"]


Out[144]= 3

Out[146]= 3

Out[147]= "Package[%s]"
```

There's a notebook with the code [here](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/user-affd7b1c-ecb6-4ccc-8cc4-4d107e2bf04a/CustomFEResources.nb) so you can download that to test it out