# Complete list of FrontEndResources

Tags: front-end, undocumented, system

#### tl;dr

I'm interested in finding a complete list of the strings that can be passed to `FrontEndResource` (I only need the first string, in the cases where two strings would normally be passed)

#### Full explanation

I've been playing with button appearances recently and I stumbled upon the `"FEExpressions"` argument to `FrontEndResource`.

This is great as it significantly improves the appearances of the my various interface components, particularly buttons and panels, as many appearances are documented there:

```
Button[
 Style["Orange Button", White],
 Appearance -> 
  FrontEndResource["FEExpressions", 
      "OrangeButtonNinePatchAppearance"]
 ]
```

which generates the following button set:

[image: Orange buttons]

Or they can be constructed from what's there already:

```
 Panel[
  InputField["", String],
  Alignment -> Center,
  Appearance -> {
   "Default" ->
     Last@Last@
      FrontEndResource["NotebookTemplatingExpressions", 
       "ButtonDefaultAppearanceCloud"],
   "Hover" ->
     Last@Last@
      FrontEndResource["NotebookTemplatingExpressions", 
        "ButtonOKAppearanceCloud"]
    }
  ]
```

[image: Input fields]

I used my standard scraping procedure on the list of them and got a seemingly pretty comprehensive list:

```
{
    "ActivationDialog",
    "CellInsertionMenu",
    "CloudDialogs",
    "CodeCaptionsText",
    "CompatibilityToolbarText",
    "ContextMenus",
    "DeployCDFDialog",
    "DrawingToolsDialog",
    "DynamicUpdatingToolbarText",
    "ExportDialogs",
    "FEBitmaps",
    "FEExpressions",
    "FEStrings",
    "FindReplaceDialog",
    "GraphicsInspectorDialog",
    "HeadersFootersDialog",
    "HelpToolbarText",
    "HistoryOverviewDialog",
    "Image3DEditModeMenu",
    "ImageEditModeMenu",
    "ImportDialogs",
    "InsertCitationDialog",
    "LicenseFailureDialog",
    "LocalizedBitmaps",
    "MathematicaClosingDialog",
    "MessageToolbarText",
    "MUnitExpressions",
    "MUnitStrings",
    "NotebookTemplatingBitmaps",
    "NotebookTemplatingExpressions",
    "NotebookTemplatingStrings",
    "PackageToolbarText",
    "PreferencesDialog",
    "ProductSpecificToolbarText",
    "RGBColorValueSelector",
    "RGBColorValueSelectorStrings",
    "SecurityToolbarText",
    "SlideshowToolbarText",
    "StylesheetThumbnails",
    "StylesheetToolbarText",
    "SystemInformationDialog",
    "TemplateBoxTooltips",
    "VersionedStylesheetToolbar",
    "WAStrings",
    "WelcomeScreen",
    "WolframCloudLoginErrors"
    };
```

Even amongst these there are many things I can't find that I know there are front-end files for, such as the images used in the toolbar buttons:

```
 Button[
  Style["Special Button", Black],
  Appearance -> {
   "Default" ->
     FrontEnd`FileName[{"Toolbars"}, "Button.9.png"],
   "Hover" -> 
     FrontEnd`FileName[{"Toolbars"}, "Button-Hover.9.png"],
   "Pressed" ->
     FrontEnd`FileName[{"Toolbars"}, "DefaultButton.9.png"]
    }]
```

[image]

Does anyone know how to find a complete list of `FrontEndResource` strings?

---

Further reading:

[Can one effectively edit a Front End Resource that is already loaded?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/121059/5478)

[How to create and use my own *.tr FrontEndResource and FrontEndResourceString files](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/127796/5478)

Comment: I think  these "resources" are in the files with `tr` extension in the TextResources directory: `FileNames["*.tr", $InstallationDirectory, Infinity]`

Comment: Ah! Right you are. `{$InstallationDirectory, "FrontEnd", "TextResources", "MiscExpressions.tr"}` has `@@resource FEExpressions` at the top. Let me do a quick scrape and we'll have the names in no time.

Comment: At least for the few I tried, the function `FrontEndResource[x]` with a single argument ( the "resource" with name x ) gives the full list of text resources under x. E.g. `FrontEndResource["ExportDialogs"]`, `First /@ FrontEndResource["FEBitmaps"]` etc.

Comment: Yep. That's a behavior I take advantage of when I'm searching for resources. Sorry, got side tracked writing grep stuff. I'll do the scrape in a moment.

Answer (score 7):

#### Leaving this open for a bit in case someone has an internal way to do this

So kglr found that all of these resources are in the .tr files and a quick glance at the files suggests that they are in files tagged with `@@resource <resource_name>`.

Grepping for that we find 1656 distinct matches.
Selecting those that don't return `$Failed` from `FrontEndResource` we get 305 matches.

```
{
     "actionNoteStringTable" ,
     "ActivationDialog" ,
     "allAutomaticFitStringTable" ,
     "allAutomaticStringTable" ,
     "allNoneAutomaticStringTable" ,
     "allowedDimensionsStringTable" ,
     "animationCountStringTable" ,
     "animationDirectionStringTable" ,
     "animatorElementsStringTable" ,
     "appearanceSizeStringTable" ,
     "appearanceStateStringTable" ,
     "AssertFailedBoxExpression" ,
     "AssertInformationFailedBoxExpression" ,
     "automaticFullStringTable" ,
     "automaticInfinityStringTable" ,
     "backgroundAppearanceOptionsStringTable" ,
     "BasicMathAssistantPalette" ,
     "boolAndAllStringTable" ,
     "boolAndAutomaticStringTable" ,
     "boolNoneAutomaticStringTable" ,
     "boolStringTable" ,
     "browserCategoryElementNotItemOrCategory" ,
     "buttonAlignmentStringTable" ,
     "buttonFrameStringTable" ,
     "buttonSourceStringTable" ,
     "cellContextStringTable" ,
     "cellFrameMarginsStringTable" ,
     "cellFrameStringTable" ,
     "CellInsertionMenu" ,
     "cellLabelPositioningStringTable" ,
     "characterEncodingStringTable" ,
     "ChartElementSchemesPalette" ,
     "CheckBoxChecked" ,
     "CheckBoxMixed" ,
     "CheckBoxUnchecked" ,
     "ClassroomAssistantPalette" ,
     "closedOpenStringTable" ,
     "CloudDialogs" ,
     "CloudLoginDialog" ,
     "CloudLoginDialogStrings" ,
     "CMYKColorValueSelectorStrings" ,
     "codeAssistIncludedCompletionsStringTable" ,
     "codeAssistMatchingAlgorithmStringTable" ,
     "codeAssistStaticMenuExpr" ,
     "CodeCaptionsText" ,
     "ColorSchemeChooserStrings" ,
     "ColorSchemesPalette" ,
     "colorSetterElementsStringTable" ,
     "columnAlignStringTable" ,
     "columnLinesStringTable" ,
     "commandTargetStringTable" ,
     "CompatibilityToolbarText" ,
     "compressedDataStringTable" ,
     "ConnectSecondaryLinks" ,
     "controlPlacementStringTable" ,
     "controlsRenderingStringTable" ,
     "conversionCellTypesStringTable" ,
     "copySpecialStringTable" ,
     "counterDataStringTable" ,
     "counterFunctionStringTable" ,
     "createGridBoxTypeStringTable" ,
     "DangerousSymbols" ,
     "DateFormat" ,
     "DayNames" ,
     "debuggerBreakpointsWindowContents" ,
     "DebuggerDialogs" ,
     "debuggerStackWindowContents" ,
     "debuggerToolsWindowContents" ,
     "defaultFormatTypeStringTable" ,
     "DefaultInlineFormatTypeStringTable" ,
     "DefaultTemplate" ,
     "DeployCDFDialog" ,
     "dingbatCellStyleStringTable" ,
     "displayImagePixelsStringTable" ,
     "DynamicUpdatingToolbarText" ,
     "evaluationCompletionStringTable" ,
     "evaluationModeStringTable" ,
     "evaluationQueueActionsTable" ,
     "ExpirationDateFormat" ,
     "ExportDialogs" ,
     "extraFrontEndSymbolsTable" ,
     "falseOrAutomaticStringTable" ,
     "FEBitmaps" ,
     "FEExpressions" ,
     "FEStrings" ,
     "fileChangeProtectionStringsTable" ,
     "fileContentsStringTable" ,
     "fileFilters" ,
     "fileLeaderTrailerStringTable" ,
     "FindReplaceDialog" ,
     "firstArgToFunctionBrowserItemNotString" ,
     "fixCoordOrAutomaticAngleStringTable" ,
     "fixCoordOrAutomaticOrFitStringTable" ,
     "fixCoordOrAutomaticStringTable" ,
     "fontPostScriptNameNoteFontStringTable" ,
     "fontsNotListedInFontsMenu" ,
     "fontTypeStringTable" ,
     "fractionMultilineStringTable" ,
     "globalVariableNamesStringTable" ,
     "graphCoord2DHorizontalStringTable" ,
     "graphCoord2DSizeStringTable" ,
     "graphCoord2DStringTable" ,
     "graphCoord2DVerticalStringTable" ,
     "graphics3DRendererStringTable" ,
     "GraphicsInspectorDialog" ,
     "graphicsPrintingFormatStringTable" ,
     "GrayLevelValueSelectorStrings" ,
     "gridboxFrameStringTable" ,
     "groupLikeCellStyleStringTable" ,
     "HeadersFootersDialog" ,
     "HelpBrowserSetup" ,
     "HelpToolbarText" ,
     "HelpViewerHistoryAction" ,
     "HistoryOverviewDialog" ,
     "horizontalAlignStringTable" ,
     "horizontalVerticalStringTable" ,
     "HueValueSelectorStrings" ,
     "hyphenationCharacterStringTable" ,
     "illegalFormatForBoxData" ,
     "illustratorColorsStringTable" ,
     "Image3DEditModeMenu" ,
     "imageCacheContentsStringTable" ,
     "ImageEditModeMenu" ,
     "imageRenderingStringTable" ,
     "imageSizeActionStringTable" ,
     "imageSizeStringTable" ,
     "ImportDialogs" ,
     "indexCreationFormatStringTable" ,
     "InputField" ,
     "InsertCitationDialog" ,
     "inspectorScopeInDialogStringTable" ,
     "inspectorScopeStringTable" ,
     "inspectorViewAsInDialogStringTable" ,
     "inspectorViewAsStringTable" ,
     "KernelPostScriptDefinitions" ,
     "KeyEventTranslations" ,
     "keysStylesStringTable" ,
     "LABColorValueSelectorStrings" ,
     "languageCategoryStringTable" ,
     "languageStringTable" ,
     "LCHColorValueSelectorStrings" ,
     "leftRightBottomTopStringTable" ,
     "leftRightStringTable" ,
     "lhsOfOptionInHelpBrowserItemNotRule" ,
     "LicenseFailureDialog" ,
     "LicensingErrors" ,
     "linebreakSemicolonWeightStringTable" ,
     "LocalizedBitmaps" ,
     "locatorAppearanceStringTable" ,
     "locatorConstraintStringTable" ,
     "LongDateFormat" ,
     "LUVColorValueSelectorStrings" ,
     "magnificationInWindowStringTable" ,
     "magnificationStringTable" ,
     "MainToolbarText" ,
     "manualAutomaticStringTable" ,
     "MathematicaClosingDialog" ,
     "menuAppearanceStringTable" ,
     "messageTimeStampFormat" ,
     "MessageToolbarText" ,
     "MonthNames" ,
     "multilineStringTable" ,
     "NamespaceBoxTooltips" ,
     "NeXTAppOpeningOptionsStringTable" ,
     "ninePatchAppearanceStringTable" ,
     "noArgumentsToFunctionBrowserItem" ,
     "noneAllStringTable" ,
     "noneAutomaticManualStringTable" ,
     "noneAutomaticNumberStringTable" ,
     "noneAutomaticStringTable" ,
     "noRhsNameStringTable" ,
     "notebookFindElementsStringTable" ,
     "notebookOpeningOptionsStringTable" ,
     "notebookRendererStringTable" ,
     "NotebookTemplatingBitmaps" ,
     "NotebookTemplatingExpressions" ,
     "NotebookTemplatingStrings" ,
     "onlyAutomaticStringTable" ,
     "onlyNoneStringTable" ,
     "optionPositionInHelpBrowserItemNotRule" ,
     "PackageTemplate" ,
     "PackageToolbarText" ,
     "pageWidthStringTable" ,
     "paletteTypeCellStyleStringTable" ,
     "paneElementsStringTable" ,
     "paperOrientationStringTable" ,
     "placeholderStringTable" ,
     "PopupMenu" ,
     "PostScriptNameToFontDescription" ,
     "postSelectionStringTable" ,
     "PredictiveInterfaceBitmaps" ,
     "PredictiveInterfaceExpressions" ,
     "PredictiveInterfaceLocalizableBitmaps" ,
     "PredictiveInterfaceStrings" ,
     "preemptiveOrQueuedStringTable" ,
     "PreferencesDialog" ,
     "ProductSpecificToolbarText" ,
     "ProgressBar" ,
     "ProgressBarBackground" ,
     "ProgressBarIndeterminate" ,
     "progressTextBackColor" ,
     "progressTextColor" ,
     "progressTextLocation" ,
     "RadioButtonChecked" ,
     "RadioButtonUnchecked" ,
     "rasterizationResolutionStringTable" ,
     "readingTypeStringTable" ,
     "relativeOrAbsoluteStringTable" ,
     "renderingDeviceStringTable" ,
     "renderingEngineStringTable" ,
     "renderingEngineWinStringTable" ,
     "renderingMethodStringTable" ,
     "reportActionStringTable" ,
     "reportConsoleActionStringTable" ,
     "RGBColorValueSelectorStrings" ,
     "rotationActionStringTable" ,
     "roundingStringTable" ,
     "rowLinesStringTable" ,
     "rulerUnitsStringTable" ,
     "SafeContexts" ,
     "SafeExpressions" ,
     "safeFileOpenStringTable" ,
     "safeFileSaveStringTable" ,
     "saveAsSpecialStringTable" ,
     "scrollPositionStringTable" ,
     "searchTypeCellStyleStringTable" ,
     "SecurityToolbarText" ,
     "selectionMoveDirectionStringTable" ,
     "selectionUnitStringTable" ,
     "ShortDayNames" ,
     "ShortMonthNames" ,
     "showAtStartupStringTable" ,
     "sizeNoteFontStringTable" ,
     "slantNoteFontStringTable" ,
     "sliderAppearanceStringTable" ,
     "SliderBackground2D" ,
     "SliderBar2DHorizontal" ,
     "SliderBar2DVertical" ,
     "SliderBarHorizontal" ,
     "SliderBarVertical" ,
     "SliderThumb2D" ,
     "SliderThumbDownArrow" ,
     "SliderThumbHorizontal" ,
     "SliderThumbLeftArrow" ,
     "SliderThumbRightArrow" ,
     "SliderThumbUpArrow" ,
     "SliderThumbVertical" ,
     "SlideShowPalette" ,
     "SlideshowToolbarText" ,
     "soundPlayerElementsStringTable" ,
     "spanMaxStringTable" ,
     "spanMinStringTable" ,
     "SpecialCharactersPalette" ,
     "specialEditButtonStringTable" ,
     "spellCheckerScopeInDialogStringTable" ,
     "spellingOptionsLanguageStringTable" ,
     "spellingOptionsWordSplittingStringTable" ,
     "spellingOptionsWordTypesStringTable" ,
     "spherCartStringTable" ,
     "statisticsDomainStringTable" ,
     "StyleDialogDockedCell" ,
     "StylesheetThumbnails" ,
     "StylesheetToolbarText" ,
     "synchronousUpdatingStringTable" ,
     "SystemInformationDialog" ,
     "SystemMenuSetup" ,
     "tabFillingStringTable" ,
     "TagBoxTooltips" ,
     "TemplateBoxTooltips" ,
     "textAlignmentStringTable" ,
     "textCapTypeStringTable" ,
     "textClipboardTypeTable" ,
     "TextDirectionIndeterminate" ,
     "textJustificationStringTable" ,
     "textScriptPositionStringTable" ,
     "TokenTranslationDictionary" ,
     "toolStringTable" ,
     "trackingNoteFontStringTable" ,
     "transitionDirectionStringTable" ,
     "transitionDurationStringTable" ,
     "transitionEffectStringTable" ,
     "twoByteSyntaxCharacterAutoReplacementsTable" ,
     "undoInformationDescriptionText" ,
     "URL2HyperlinkTemplate" ,
     "urlPrefixStrings" ,
     "VersionedStylesheetToolbar" ,
     "verticalAlignStringTable" ,
     "viewProjectionStringTable" ,
     "WABitmaps" ,
     "WAExpressions" ,
     "WALocalizableBitmaps" ,
     "WAStrings" ,
     "weightNoteFontStringTable" ,
     "WelcomeScreen" ,
     "windowElementsStringTable" ,
     "windowFrameElementsStringTable" ,
     "windowFrameStringTable" ,
     "windowSizeStringTable" ,
     "windowTitleStringTable" ,
     "windowToolbarsStringTable" ,
     "WolframCloudLoginErrors" ,
     "WolframCloudSyncToolbar" ,
     "WritingAssistantPalette" ,
     "xyAlignmentStringTable" ,
     "XYZColorValueSelectorStrings" 
    }
```

Of these, 61 have sub-resources (the type of thing I'm most interested in):

```
{
     "ActivationDialog" ,
     "CloudDialogs" ,
     "CloudLoginDialog" ,
     "CloudLoginDialogStrings" ,
     "CMYKColorValueSelectorStrings" ,
     "CodeCaptionsText" ,
     "ColorSchemeChooserStrings" ,
     "CompatibilityToolbarText" ,
     "DebuggerDialogs" ,
     "DeployCDFDialog" ,
     "DynamicUpdatingToolbarText" ,
     "ExportDialogs" ,
     "FEBitmaps" ,
     "FEExpressions" ,
     "FEStrings" ,
     "FindReplaceDialog" ,
     "GraphicsInspectorDialog" ,
     "GrayLevelValueSelectorStrings" ,
     "HeadersFootersDialog" ,
     "HelpToolbarText" ,
     "HistoryOverviewDialog" ,
     "HueValueSelectorStrings" ,
     "Image3DEditModeMenu" ,
     "ImageEditModeMenu" ,
     "ImportDialogs" ,
     "InsertCitationDialog" ,
     "LABColorValueSelectorStrings" ,
     "LCHColorValueSelectorStrings" ,
     "LicenseFailureDialog" ,
     "LicensingErrors" ,
     "LocalizedBitmaps" ,
     "LUVColorValueSelectorStrings" ,
     "MathematicaClosingDialog" ,
     "MessageToolbarText" ,
     "NotebookTemplatingBitmaps" ,
     "NotebookTemplatingExpressions" ,
     "NotebookTemplatingStrings" ,
     "PackageToolbarText" ,
     "PredictiveInterfaceBitmaps" ,
     "PredictiveInterfaceExpressions" ,
     "PredictiveInterfaceStrings" ,
     "PreferencesDialog" ,
     "ProductSpecificToolbarText" ,
     "RGBColorValueSelectorStrings" ,
     "SecurityToolbarText" ,
     "SlideshowToolbarText" ,
     "StylesheetThumbnails" ,
     "StylesheetToolbarText" ,
     "SystemInformationDialog" ,
     "TemplateBoxTooltips" ,
     "twoByteSyntaxCharacterAutoReplacementsTable" ,
     "undoInformationDescriptionText" ,
     "VersionedStylesheetToolbar" ,
     "WABitmaps" ,
     "WAExpressions" ,
     "WALocalizableBitmaps" ,
     "WAStrings" ,
     "WelcomeScreen" ,
     "WolframCloudLoginErrors" ,
     "WolframCloudSyncToolbar" ,
     "XYZColorValueSelectorStrings" 
    }
```

And then of these 10 contain "Bitmaps" or "Expressions" in their names:

```
{
     "FEBitmaps" ,
     "FEExpressions" ,
     "LocalizedBitmaps" ,
     "NotebookTemplatingBitmaps" ,
     "NotebookTemplatingExpressions" ,
     "PredictiveInterfaceBitmaps" ,
     "PredictiveInterfaceExpressions" ,
     "WABitmaps" ,
     "WAExpressions" ,
     "WALocalizableBitmaps" 
    }
```

There are two more possible matches: `"PredictiveInterfaceLocalizableBitmaps"` and `"SafeExpressions"` but the first is an empty list for me and the second returns `` FEPrivate`FrontEndResource["SafeExpressions"] `` and it's unclear how to convert it into a proper expression (`` FE`Evaluate `` has no effect here).