# How can I create a help button that looks more "professional"?

Tags: front-end, customization, style, button

My goal, is to make the following button,

```
Button[Style["?", Black, Bold], MessageDialog[Column[{Style["Help", Bold, Black, FontSize
-> 12],"Some Text Here"}], WindowTitle -> "Help", Background -> White]];
```

look more like a "canonical" help button. If we take a look at most programs, these types of buttons have a distinguished stylization.

An example could be:

[image]

How would I achieve this in *Mathematica* while keeping the same structure of my above code?

Comment: Have you tried some graphics or image instead of `Style["?", Black, Bold]`?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I  tried Button[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugb7b.png"], 
 MessageDialog[
  Column[{Style["Help", Bold, Black, FontSize -> 12], 
    "Some Text Here"}], WindowTitle -> "Help", Background -> White]]

Comment: Mike's answer is pretty much what I had in mind, and pretty much equivalent to what you tried.  The buttons of most programs are designed by their development team (or they pay a designer to do it).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Why not just use the graphic in the question, or any other images that you like:

[image]

Use `ImageSize` to control the final size of the button:

[image]

An alternative, that I use in some applications, is something like this:

```
help[$helpmessage_: "", $videolink_: ""] := 
  ActionMenu[
   Graphics[{{RGBColor[0.689647, 0.761166, 0.805478], 
      Disk[{0, 0}, 0.1]}, {GrayLevel[0], Circle[{0, 0}, 0.1], 
      Style[Inset["?", {0.01, 0}], "Label", FontSize -> 11]}},
    ImageSize -> {20, 20}],
   {"Help Notes" :> MessageDialog[
      Grid[{
        {Style[$helpmessage, LineIndent -> 0]}
        },
       Alignment -> {Center, Center},
       ItemSize -> {Automatic, All},
       Spacings -> {0, 0}],
      Background -> White],
    "View Video" :> SystemOpen[$videolink]},
   Appearance -> None,
   BaseStyle -> {},
   FrameMargins -> {{0, 0}, {-2, -2}},
   ImageSize -> {20, 20}];
```

[image]

Comment: Yes I was thinking about using import, but I wanted to know is there was a way to do it only with Mathematica functions. Anyways, is there a way to make the image smaller? Would Image size still work in this case?

Comment: @user372003 you don't need to import, just cut/copy and paste. See the edit for using ImageSize

Answer (score 11):

Here's the general way this type of thing seems to be handled in the built-in things plus code to build the type of buttons you want.

First the button code:

```
makeDisk[gradSpec_, n_] :=
  Rasterize[
   Module[{img, disk, edge},
    img =
     RadialGradientImage[
      gradSpec,
      n
      ];
    Graphics[
     {
      Inset[img, Center, Center, Scaled[1]],
      White,
      Annulus[{0, 0}, {1, 2}],
      GrayLevel[.8],
      EdgeForm[Gray],
      Annulus[{0, 0}, {1, 1.1}]
      },
     Background -> None,
     PlotRange -> {{-1.2, 1.2}, {-1.2, 1.2}},
     ImageSize -> n
     ]
    ],
   Background -> None
   ];
With[{n = 80},
 imOut =
  makeDisk[
   {{.8*n, 5}, {n, n}} ->
    {Hue[.6, .6, 1], Hue[.6, 1, 1], 
     Hue[.6, .3, 1]}, 
   n
   ];
 imHov =
  makeDisk[
   {{.8*n, 5}, {n, n}} ->
    {Hue[.6, .4, 1], Hue[.6, .8, 1], 
     Hue[.6, .3, 1]}, 
    n
   ];
 imIn =
  makeDisk[
   {{.3*n, .6*n}, {n, 5}} ->

    Reverse@{Hue[.6, .6, 1], Hue[.6, 1, 1], Hue[.6, 1, 1]},
    n
   ];
 {imOut, imHov, imIn}
 ]
```

[image: asdasdasd]

And here's a way to get hover actions and things:

```
Button[
 Style["asd", White, Bold],
 Appearance ->
  {
   "Default" -> imOut,
   "Hover" -> imHov,
   "Pressed" -> imIn
   }
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: looks like the `Appearance` option only takes bitmap images (not primitives)?

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch it only takes images, but crucially it can take nine patch images so it can resize adaptively.

Comment: presumably the wolfram bitmaps are 9 patch?

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch exactly. I posted an answer about how to make these which shows the utility of them.

Answer (score 10):

A couple of images that come with *Mathematica*.  Caveat: There's no guarantee that they will be present in all (future) versions.

```
Button[
 Import[FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", 
    "FrontEnd", "SystemResources", "Bitmaps", "Popups", 
    "CodeCompletion", "MenuItemHelpTiny@144dpi.png"}]
  ],
 Beep[], (* your help dialog here *)
 Appearance -> "Frameless"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Button[
 Import[FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", 
    "FrontEnd", "SystemResources", "Bitmaps", "Ribbons", "Common", 
    "Help@144dpi.png"}]
  ],
 Beep[], (* your help dialog here *)
 Appearance -> "Frameless"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

*Update*

These change color slightly when the mouse is over the button:

```
Button[
 Mouseover[
  Import[FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", 
     "FrontEnd", "SystemResources", "Bitmaps", "Popups", 
     "CodeCompletion", "MenuItemHelpTiny@144dpi.png"}]
   ],
  Import[FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", 
     "FrontEnd", "SystemResources", "Bitmaps", "Popups", 
     "CodeCompletion", "MenuItemHelpHoverTiny@144dpi.png"}]
   ]
  ],
 Beep[],
 Appearance -> "Frameless"]

Button[
 Mouseover[
  Import[FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", 
     "FrontEnd", "SystemResources", "Bitmaps", "Ribbons", "Common", 
     "Help@144dpi.png"}]
   ],
  Import[FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", 
     "FrontEnd", "SystemResources", "Bitmaps", "Ribbons", "Common", 
     "HelpHighlight@144dpi.png"}]
   ]
  ],
 Beep[], 
 Appearance -> "Frameless"]
```

Comment: Oh Wow! I did not know about this!

Comment: based on [138889](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/138889/5478) it can be reduced to: ``Button["",
 Beep[],
 Appearance -> {"Default" -> 
    FrontEnd`FileName[{"Ribbons", "Common"}, "Help@144dpi.png"]
   , "Hover" -> 
    FrontEnd`FileName[{"Ribbons", "Common"}, 
     "HelpHighlight@144dpi.png"]
   }]``

Answer (score 4):

When I tried using the methods described here based on the `Appearance` option for `Button` it seems that only bitmaps were valid, i.e. primitives didn't seem to be valid ...unless I have not coded correctly.

I normally prefer not to use bitmap images in interfaces because the aesthetics breaks down when the magnification changes -- you can always lock that down but not ideal for your users. Appearance differs across platforms as well. So in an ideal world buttons and controls based on primitives are better.

By redefining @b3m2a1 function this can be achieved:

```
makeDisk2[gradSpec_, n_] :=
  Module[{img, disk, edge},
   img = RadialGradientImage[gradSpec, n];
   Graphics[{
     Inset[img, Center, Center, Scaled[1]],
     White, Annulus[{0, 0}, {1, 2}], GrayLevel[.8], EdgeForm[Gray], 
     Annulus[{0, 0}, {1, 1.1}]},
    Background -> None,
    PlotRange -> {{-1.2, 1.2}, {-1.2, 1.2}},
    ImageSize -> n]];

With[{n = 30},
 imOut1 = 
  makeDisk2[{{.8*n, 5}, {n, n}} -> {Hue[.6, .6, 1], Hue[.6, 1, 1], 
     Hue[.6, .3, 1]}, n];
 imHov1 = 
  makeDisk2[{{.8*n, 5}, {n, n}} -> {Hue[.6, .4, 1], Hue[.6, .8, 1], 
     Hue[.6, .3, 1]}, n];
 imIn1 = makeDisk2[{{.3*n, .6*n}, {n, 5}} -> 
    Reverse@{Hue[.6, .6, 1], Hue[.6, 1, 1], Hue[.6, 1, 1]}, n];
 {imOut1, imHov1, imIn1}
 ]

Button[Dynamic@Overlay[{
    Which[
     CurrentValue["MouseOver"] == True&&CurrentValue["MouseButtons"] == {1}, button = imIn1,
     CurrentValue["MouseOver"] == True, button = imHov1,
     True, button = imOut1],
    Style["?", White, 18, Bold]
    },
   Alignment -> Center],
 Appearance -> None]
```

here is a pick of primitive (top) and raster buttons (bottom) at 100%

[image]

and again at 200%

[image]