# Copy graphical style of Slider2D

Tags: plotting, graphics, output-formatting

`Slider2D@{.5,.5}` makes a draggable orange point with gray lines in a square.

[image: slider2d]

I want to use that dot in my plots.  I also want to use that color and thickness of gray line.  I could extract all of this information approximately from the image.  But I think there's a way to get the pieces used to construct that object in a way analagous to `FullForm@Slider2D@{.5,.5}` (this code of course does not yield a list of lines, other graphics primitives etc.).  Perhaps the solution involves `FullGraphics` or `AbsoluteOptions` or `AbsoluteCurrentValue`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The orange png image used as slider thumb:

```
slider2dThumb = Import["C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram Research\\Mathematica\\11.3\\SystemFiles\\FrontEnd\\SystemResources\\\
Bitmaps\\Typeset\\Slider2D\\ThumbLarge.png"]
```

[image]

`GrayLevel` graphics objects:

```
FrontEndResource["SliderThumb2D"] // Short
```

[image]

```
RawBoxes /@ {FrontEndResource["SliderThumb2D"], 
  FrontEndResource["SliderBackground2D"], 
  FrontEndResource["SliderBar2DHorizontal"], 
  FrontEndResource["SliderBar2DVertical"]}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there documentation for `FrontEndResource`?  In my version, 12.1, I can't find `FrontEndResource` even in Names["FrontEnd\`*"]

Comment: No, it is not documented.

Comment: @Adam, it is one of those undocumented internal functions. For related Q/As on this site, see,  for example, [Complete list of FrontEndResources](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/138889/125).

Answer (score 5):

I don't think this is actually made with Wolfram graphics primitives, but you can still find the image it uses! Open the application package and navigate to `Contents > SystemFiles > FrontEnd > SystemResources > Bitmaps > Typeset > Slider2D`. (That's where the orange disk is on a Mac, anyway.) You have a choice of different sizes.

I found what might be the rest of the information in the file `Contents > SystemFiles > FrontEnd > TextResources > Controls.tr`. If you find `Slider2D` in that document, you can see that the resource `SliderBar2DHorizontal`, for example, is given as

```
GraphicsBox[{GrayLevel[0.65], AbsoluteThickness[1.5], 
  LineBox[{{0, 0}, {4, 0}}]}, PlotRange -> {{-0.25, 4.25}, {-0.3, 0.3}}]
```

`GraphicsBox` is a lower-level undocumented form of `Graphics` that represents graphics as an expression per se, so applying `ToExpression` or, to be more precise, `RawBoxes`, works.

**Edit:** Also see @klgr's answer for a demonstration of using `FrontEndResource` within Mathematica to get this information! :)

Comment: ah...klgr beat me by about 10 seconds, looks like! well, their answer is more comprehensive anyway, given that it employs `FrontEndResource`. Though, I suppose it doesn't mention the file `Controls.tr`, so I've at least contributed something... :)

Comment: I've never gone spelunking in /opt/Mathematica before, thank you for the intro! (unix master race)

Comment: Ah, is it under `/opt` for you? (Are you on Linux?) For me it's literally inside the application itself!

Comment: The Mac toolbar is full of surprises!  I don't have `Controls` in my Notebook -- nice to have `find / -name "Controls.tr"` in a linux bash shell though.

Comment: Oh, not the toolbar! (That would really be something!) I mean I navigate to Mathematica.app, then "show package contents". Ah, very nice!