# How to work with BoxOptions (ButtonBoxOptions, PanelBoxOptions, etc.)

Tags: front-end, options, boxes, system, guidelines

The main question is in the title. Here are subtopics I'd like to focus on:

1. Is there a **tutorial** related to them anywhere in documentation?
2. How can I check what are **current values** of e.g. `ButtonBoxOptions`?

   Are documentation pages for specific symbols the only source of this information?
3. How are they related to what `CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "Input", ButtonBoxOptions}]` gives:

   > {ButtonBoxOptionsBaseStyle -> "GenericButton", ...
4. What is their **place and advantages** in **styles resolving scheme**?

   I suspect they are applied somewhere around `MakeBoxes` but is this documented somewhere?

   They also allow to style boxes collectively ([**with limitations**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/115888/evaluation-leak-from-dynamic-in-buttons-action/116030#comment315016_116030)), is that all?
5. Can **analogous options for custom boxes** be created or it is not meant to be accessible from user side?
6. Do they work consistently or are they full of exceptions?

   I failed to understand why `PanelBox` case works but `TemplateBox` doesn't:

   ```
   Style[
    Panel[1],
    PanelBoxOptions -> {Background -> Red} (*works well*)
   ]

   Style[
     TraditionalForm @ Binomial[a, b],
     TemplateBoxOptions -> {Tooltip -> None} (*fails, tooltip is there*)
   ]
   ```

   So it seems `TemplateBox` escapes a standard resolution scheme. What I intuitively get but I would like to have this explained.

Comment: `TemplateBoxOptions -> {Tooltip -> None}` is the default `Tooltip` option value. `Style[TraditionalForm@Binomial[a, b], 
 TemplateBoxOptions -> {TooltipDelay -> Infinity}]` or `Style[TraditionalForm@Binomial[a, b], 
 TemplateBoxOptions -> {TooltipStyle -> Directive[Red, Bold]}]` do work as expected.

Comment: @Karsten7.  I'm not sure I got your point. For a `Binomial's` template the default is `Tooltip -> Automatic`, defined in `Core.nb` and it overwrites my `Tooltip->None` even though I've put that setting on expression level.

Comment: I don't know about the "Binomial's template". All I meant was that the option setting `Tooltip -> None` is the default for `TemplateBoxOptions` and changing other option settings for `TemplateBoxOptions` do have the expected effect. Therefore my expectation for using `TemplateBoxOptions -> {Tooltip -> None}` was that it doesn't have any effect, but now I understand that you expected it to change the settings inherited from the "Binomial's template".

Comment: @Karsten7. yep I wasn't clear in that. There is a `"Binomial"` style in Core.nb with `TemplateBoxOptions`.

Answer (score 3):

> **2. How can I check what are current values of e.g. ButtonBoxOptions?**

One can get the current values for the `$FrontEnd` using for example

```
Options[$FrontEnd, ButtonBoxOptions]
```

> ```
> {ButtonBoxOptions -> {Active -> True, Alignment -> {Automatic, Automatic},     
>    Appearance -> {Automatic, "Palette"}, AutoAction -> False, 
>    Background -> Automatic, BaseStyle -> "GenericButton", 
>    BaselinePosition -> Automatic, ButtonData -> Automatic, 
>    ButtonFunction :> (FrontEndExecute[{FrontEnd`NotebookApply[
>          FrontEnd`InputNotebook[], #1, Placeholder]}] &), ButtonMargins -> 3, 
>    ButtonMinHeight -> 1., ButtonNote -> None, ButtonSource -> Automatic, 
>    ContentPadding -> True, DefaultBaseStyle -> "Button", 
>    DefaultTooltipStyle -> "TooltipLabel", Enabled -> Automatic, 
>    Evaluator -> None, FrameMargins -> Automatic, ImageMargins -> Automatic, 
>    ImageSize -> Full, Method -> "Queued", Tooltip -> None, TooltipDelay -> 0.,
>     TooltipStyle -> {}}}
> ```

```
Options[$FrontEnd, TemplateBoxOptions]
```

> ```
> {TemplateBoxOptions -> {BaseStyle -> {}, DefaultBaseStyle -> {}, 
>    DefaultTooltipStyle -> "TooltipLabel", DisplayFunction -> None, 
>    Editable -> Automatic, Inactive -> False, InactiveStyle -> "InactiveStyle",
>     InterpretationFunction -> Automatic, Selectable -> Automatic, 
>    SyntaxForm -> Automatic, Tooltip -> None, TooltipDelay -> 0., 
>    TooltipStyle -> {}}}
> ```

In the Option Inspector they can be found under
Formatting Options ► Expression Formatting ► Controls Options or Specific Box Options